# ruby on rails - NoMethodError on has_many relation - trying to create a categories and subcategories model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a app that will have Categories and Subcategories. So I have created both models with scaffold.

I am getting this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `subcategories' for #<Category::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f96e144d458>)
```

But the relation is on the model is a `has_many` and `belong_to`

Here is my models:

`models/category.rb`

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories
end
```

`models/subcategory.rb`

```rb
class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

here is the controller

`controllers/pages_controller.rb`

```rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @categories = Category.all
    @subcategories = @categories&.subcategories || []
  end

  private
    def find_mmy
      @category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category].presence)
      @subcategory = Subcategory.find_by(id: params[:subcategory].presence)
    end
end
```

And the view `views/home.html.erb`:

```html
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>

<%= turbo_frame_tag "form" do %>
  <%= form_tag root_path, method: :get, data: { controller: "dropdown", action: "change->dropdown#submit" } do %>
    <%= select_tag :category, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "name", @category&.id), prompt: "- Please select -" %>
    <%= select_tag :subcategory, options_from_collection_for_select(@subcategories, "id", "name", @subcategories&.id), prompt: "- Model -" %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I also created a file called `javascript/controllers/dropdown_controller.js`

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="dropdown"
export default class extends Controller {
  submit() {
    this.element.requestSubmit();
  }
}
```

Sorry, I am beginner, if my question is not clear or missing some information, just help me to make it more clear. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@categories` is a collection so you can't call `subcategories` method for it. You need to call `subcategories` method for every category like this:

```rb
@categories.map(&:subcategories)
```

this will return an array of arrays so you need to `flatten` it. also this array may have duplicate record so you need to call `uniq` method. and you don't need to assign default  value as array because it will return array anyway. Here is the final form of the answer:

```rb
@categories.map(&:subcategories).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: Instead of `@categories.map(&:subcategories).flatten.uniq` you can write `@categories.flat_map(&:subcategories).uniq`.